# HCF of two integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that whatever may be the integers $x$and $y$ the HCF of $13x+4y$ and $29x+9y$ is equal to HCF of $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\small\text{hcf}(13x+4y, 29x+9y)=\text{hcf}(13x+4y, -2(13x+4y)+29x+4y)=\text{hcf}(13x+4y, 3x+y)$$ and we have that $$13x+4y-4(3x+y)=x$$

Comment: The expression $13x + 4y - 4(3x + y) = x$, which yields $\operatorname{hcf}(x, 3x + y)$, from which the result can be obtained readily.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Fixed typo, thanks! Was typing on a phone :)